# Can't connect StrongLoop with AWS RDS MySQL instance

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, strongloop, amazon-rds

I setup an AWS RDS MySQL instance and was able to connect to it successfully using MySQL Workbench.

However when I use StrongLoop Arc to Test Connection to this MySQL instance using the same credentials, I keep getting a Handshake inactivity timeout error.

Any idea why MySQL Workbench can connect to this MySQL instance but StrongLoop can't?

Comment: Were you able to find a workaround for this? I'm having the same issue.